# Changing the size of cell borders in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

PHPExcel border styles are defined as constants in `PHPExcel_Style_Border` class. The solid ones are `BORDER_THIN`, `BORDER_MEDIUM` and `BORDER_THICK`. However, the medium and thick ones are way too thick for my needs. Is there a way to manually set the border thickness?

Comment: I don't know the class, but what are the constants defined as, what are their values? It might be possible to work from there

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but they are defined as, for example `const BORDER_MEDIUM = 'medium';` - so no help here.

Comment: Have you tried to set value like '3pt' or so?

Comment: PHPExcel border styles are defined to mimic those available in MS Excel itself... I don't believe that you can adjust the border size in MS Excel outside of those pre-defined options, so it's difficult to advise you on what to do if you consider MS Excel's options are inadequate.

Comment: As far as I can remember (I don't have MS Excel anywhere near me at the moment) you can change the border width, which is a different parameter than border style. So far I couldn't find a way to set it in PHPExcel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPExcel border styles are defined to mimic those available in MS Excel itself
The ECMA OfficeOpenXML specification (3rd Edition) defines available border styles in the ST_BorderStyle section of the document (section 18.18.3, pages 2671-2673) and defined in the xsd as:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="ST_BorderStyle">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="none"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="thin"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="medium"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="dashed"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="dotted"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="thick"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="double"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="hair"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="mediumDashed"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="dashDot"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="mediumDashDot"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="dashDotDot"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="mediumDashDotDot"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="slantDashDot"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

This follows the list of border styles defined for the BIFF file format, and I can't find any provision for defining custom styling or sizes.

**EDIT**

The Complex Border style simply adds colour information to the formatting

```
<xsd:complexType name="CT_Border">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="start" type="CT_BorderPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="end" type="CT_BorderPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="top" type="CT_BorderPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="bottom" type="CT_BorderPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="diagonal" type="CT_BorderPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="vertical" type="CT_BorderPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="horizontal" type="CT_BorderPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="diagonalUp" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="diagonalDown" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="outline" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" default="true"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="CT_BorderPr">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="color" type="CT_Color" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="style" type="ST_BorderStyle" use="optional" default="none"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```